# How get a list from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I create an array of list.
But when try to iterate for the array get a convert type error.

```
List<Piece> [] CombinationBottom1;

foreach (List<Piece> lp in CombinationTop1[0])
{
}
```

> Cannot convert type 'Test.Piece' to   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Isn't  `CombinationTop1[0]` a `List<Piece>` ??

I could create a `List<List<Piece>>` But I would like to access the Nth element and is easier using array.

For example this work ok:

```
List<List<Piece>> CombinationBottom1;

foreach (List<Piece> lp in CombinationTop1)
{
}
```

Comment: That is because `CombinationTop1[0]` is a list... you should do `foreach (Piece p in CombinationTop1[0])`

Comment: Your codes are not similar. First one should be `foreach (List<Piece> lp in CombinationBottom1)` or `foreach(Piece lp in CombinationBottom1[0])`

Comment: I see why i got confused. Now I create another `class L_Pieces = List<Piece>` So the first one is `List<L_Piece> [] CombinationBottom1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `CombinationTop1[0]` is a list... you should do

```
List<Piece> [] CombinationBottom1;

foreach (Piece p in CombinationTop1[0])
{
}
```